# How to put a Kubernetes or Docker Swarm service behind a firewall

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I have been playing a little with Kubernetes and Docker Swarm as two alternatives for managing containers in a self-hosted solution. What I could not find a straight forward answer to, is how should I put a service behind a firewall in each of them.

From what I saw in Docker Swarm and also in Kubernetes (when using NodePort), eventually a service is exposed on the IP addresses of the hosts running in the cluster, and requests are being routed to the services running in the cluster, regardless of the host you hit.

Now suppose I want to put a service behind a firewall.I need an IP address to configure in the FW as the target IP address, right? I don't want to use any specific host IP address because eventually hosts may come and go, and I don't want a single host as a single-point-of-failure.

Any pointers are highly appreciated!

Comment: For k8s checkout the [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) documentation. I think what you are looking for are designated edge router nodes in your cluster. On those nodes you could then enforce your firewall policies.

Answer (score 0):

technically, what you put behind firewall is not your service, but a whole Kubernetes cluster. If you have a solid support for LoadBalancer type service, it will get exposed with some public IP, through the LB, hence traffic will pass `Client` > `LB` > `ClusterNodes`. As you see, all yopu need is to allow connections from load balancer to cluster nodes.

In some provisioners / environments you will get this kind of behaviour by default. For example KOPS, when provisioned with `private` topology, will put your cluster nodes in an internal network which is closed for connections from ourside world other then via LB (or bastion)

Comment: Yes, when you have a load balancer provided, it's pretty straight forward. But if you don't (you're running in your own datacenter), then you need to deploy it, and then you need to take into account its HA, zero-downtime upgrades, etc., which are the problems solved in the cluster. So if you put it in the cluster, you are again in the same situation. Otherwise you need to fine an alternative way to deploy it, which is kind of frustrating.

Comment: even in your own DC you do usualy have some decent network equipment which can be used as loadbalancer. You can also deploy Ingress Controller and statically configure your network to point to it from some IP, or you can have ie. HAProxy loadbalancer exposing your public services to the world. All in all, it is very rare that you would need outside world, other then your own, known networking components (like LB/proxy etc.), to access your NodePort services directly.